# What is the difference between main in C & C++

Tags: c++, c, c++11

What is the difference between `main` in a C program and in a C++ program?

Other than

1. return statement ( default 1 in C,`0 in C++)
2. syntax:

   ```
   int main() { /* … */ }
   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* … */ }
   int main() ,  void main() ,etc ...
   ```

Mainly:

1. difference between main in C Program & C++ program
2. Are there any differences between C++98, C++03 and C++0x according to the ISO standard? i.e program's entry point (program startup implementation), etc.

Comment: *return statement & parameters of main* — that's all there is to know and all that the standard can talk about

Comment: That comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: @David : thank Q for your answer , can u aable to answer about my 2nd question ,.... regarding c++98,c++03,c++0x is there any difference in main

Comment: in c++ the return value for main should indicate how the program exited. Normal exit is generally represented by a 0 return value from main. Abnormal termination is usually signalled by a non-zero return ..

Comment: the standard does not talk about such things

Comment: Re "return statement ( default 1 in C ,0 in C++)": The default return in C98 is EXIT_SUCCESS, which is typically #defined to 0.

Comment: Isnt there a version of main which takes environment variables too?
like `int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* env[])` or is it only for gcc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In modern C, and modern C++:

- `main` is always either `int main()` or `int main(int, char*[])`.
- In C89, you have to `return` from main explicitly.
- In C99 and C++, if you don't return explicitly, you implicitly `return 0`.

[*(I've checked the C99 standard now and edited this paragraph.)*] For your second question, in C99 you must have precisely one of the two `main` functions. In C++ the standard says that a program is well-formed if it has a `main` function that returns `int`, and that every conforming implementation must accept the two listed versions as an entry point (for a "hosted program", e.g. not for the Linux kernel); see 3.6.1. [/edit] To the best of my knowledge, *calling conventions* are also not part of the standard.

I don't understand your question about memory, but do note that neither C99 nor C++03 have anything but a rudimentary memory model, whereas the new C++0x explicitly adds a memory model in order to enable well-defined concurrent and atomic operations.

Comment: In c++, a conforming implementation can accept other different signatures for main, as long as it does accept those two.

Comment: No, in all your three points. (1) for C you should note `int main(void)` since `int main()` has a different meaning in C than in C++. (2) In C99 you don't have to return explicitly from `main`. IIRC the return value defaults to `EXIT_SUCCESS`. (3) The implicit return value in C++ is `EXIT_SUCESS`, too, which in many cases is `0` but needs not to be so.

Comment: @Jens: N3242 says in 3.6.1 that if there's no return statement, you get implicit `return 0`. I'll update the C99 one, though, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Jens: What's the difference between `main()` and `main(void)`?

Comment: @Kerrek, in C an empty argument list is not a prototype but defines a function that takes an unspecified number of arguments.

Comment: @Jens: I'm suspicious: C99 says, "An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters." Your statement is only true for declarations without definition, so it looks like if I say `int main() { }` I'm fine.

Comment: @Kerrek: `int main() { }` is a definition (and a declaration); `int main();` is a declaration; `int main(void);` is a prototype (and a declaration).

Comment: @David Rodríguez -- I think it's precluded by 3.6.1/2: *This function shall not be overloaded*

Comment: @Gene: Well, you can only have one `main` in any given program, but it can have arbitrary signature, as long as it returns `int`, and it's still a well-formed program. It might just not work on your platform. :-)

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: Extending the same quote from the standard §3.6.1/2: *An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.* The *type* in the last sentence means the *arguments* to `main`.

Answer (score 8):

In C, as opposed to C++, `main` can be called recursively.

```
/* valid C */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  putchar(argc ? '.' : '\n');
  if (argc == 0) return 0;
  return main(argc - 1, NULL);
}
```

Comment: @Kerrek: 3.6.1/3: "The function main shall not be used within a program."

Answer (score 1):

C99 and C++ are put in line for the definition of `main` in hosted environments. There are two function interfaces that are allowed

```
int main(void);
int main(int, char*[]);
```

Both languages allow the implicit return from `main` without `return` statement in which case a return value of `EXIT_SUCCESS` is returned to the caller.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188335/why-default-return-value-of-main-is-0-and-not-exit-success): The implicit return is `0`, not `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: I can't speak for C, but C++ returns 0, not `EXIT_SUCCESS`.  Both are treated as "successful" return values, though, for whatever that means to the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: Is there any difference in program startup implementation is there any difference in c++98,C++03,C+++0x main ,etc.........

Not in `main`. However, there is a huge difference in what happens **before** main is called in C versus C++. In C++, objects with `static` storage are typically initialized prior to entering `main`.

**Note:**
An implementation is allowed to perform dynamic initializations of static data in the midst of `main`, but it must do so prior to the first reference to that static data. I've never run across an implementation that takes advantage of this flexibility.

Comment: it's pretty typical an implementation would defer the dynamic initialization until the first use, you just need to check optimized assembly code.