# EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE. Is it compile once run anywhere or write once compile everywhere?

Tags: c++, c, return, std, exit-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(C/C++) return EXIT_SUCCESS or 0 from main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/c-c-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main)

For a long time I was using return 0;, from the time I started to use allegro. Than I came across C++ book and found about EXIT_SUCCESS, than I looked into stdlib.h or cstdlib where it's defined and there is only two lines:

```
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1
```

can somebody explain this to me? I am using mingw version of the last devc++ 4.9.9.2.

Comment: What's to explain? You should typically return 0 from `main` to indicate success and any other value for failure.

Comment: you can use either, however there is no standard way to exit with failure unless you use EXIT_FAILURE. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/c-c-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main

Comment: @chris `0` is required to mean success, but there is no other requirement concerning values other than `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS`.  Even in common systems: under Unix, `256` will be treated as success (because the OS only keeps the low order 8 bits), and in other systems, the sky's the limit: negative or odd values are failure, or...  Also of course: Unix and Windows simply pass this value up to the invoking program.  Which interprets it as it wishes.  C++ can express an intention here, but the program which invokes your program isn't subject to the C++ standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Yes, I should have been more clear. I was talking in context of a program calling yours. Zero is, by convention, success, and I can't talk with too much experience about other OSes, but Windows is conventionally any other value for failure.

Comment: @chris Don't worry about it.  I'm being a bit pedantic.  But the fact remains that the C++ standard can only specify C++, and that everything in it which involves interaction with the external environment can really only be taken as intent in the standard, because the C++ standard can't specify the external environment.  It cannot, for example, prevent me from writing a script which tests whether `$? = 3` to determine that the program has succeeded.  (But that's obviously _not_ the convention in the Unix world.)

Answer (score 7):

The C99 language standard defines the two macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` to expand to "integer constant expressions that can be used as the argument to the
`exit` function to return unsuccessful or successful termination status, respectively, to the
host environment" (§7.20/3).

In the description of the `exit` function (§7.20.4.3/5), it also says:

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of `status` is zero or
>   `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status *successful termination* is
>   returned. If the value of `status` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form
>   of the status *unsuccessful termination* is returned. Otherwise the status returned is
>   implementation-defined.

So, if you exit with 0 or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, that always means "successful termination" to the host environment.  `EXIT_FAILURE` is a value that will always mean "unsuccessful termination", but any non-zero value other than those is not guaranteed to be portable.

Note that returning from `main` is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with a status of the return value (§5.1.2.2.3).

Comment: The remark about return from main is true in C, but it is *not* true in C++. `exit` does not call destructors of local variables. `return` from main, like return from any other function, will call destructors as the objects go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are Standard C macros defined in `stdlib.h`. C does not specify the value of these macros.

POSIX requires `EXIT_SUCCESS` to be `0`. (But does not specify anything for `EXIT_FAILURE` value).

Comment: C does not specify the value of `EXIT_SUCCESS` but it *does* specify that returning `0` from `main` has the same *effect* as returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`.  There *were* platforms (older VMS, if memory serves) that did not define `EXIT_SUCCESS` as zero *and* did not treat returning zero from main as successful termination, but that was a failure to conform to the standard.

Comment: @Zack it means `EXIT_SUCCESS` value can be 42 even if the value `0`  means a successfull termination.

Comment: Sure it can; all I'm saying is `return 0;` from `main` is a perfectly conformant way to terminate a program successfully.