# EXIT_FAILURE vs exit(1)?

Tags: c, exit

What's the difference? Which is preferred, or when should I use each one respectively?

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8867871/827263

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`exit(1)` (usually) indicates unsuccessful termination. However, its usage is non-portable. For example, on [OpenVMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS), `exit(1)` actually indicates success.

Only `EXIT_FAILURE` is the standard value for returning unsuccessful termination, but `1` is used for the same in many implementations.

---

So to summarize:
If you want to write perfectly portable code use,

`EXIT_FAILURE` for failure case. While,
You can use either `exit(0)` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` for success case.

Note that, `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `0` are both same.

---

Reference:

**C99 Standard:    7.20.4.3 The `exit` function**
**Para 5**

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is `zero` or
>   `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-deﬁned form of the status successful termination is
>   returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-deﬁned form
>   of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is
>   implementation-deﬁned.

Comment: The answer states: "`EXIT_FAILURE` for non failure case." Do you mean: "`EXIT_FAILURE` for failure case?"

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Yes. Nicely spotted.

Answer (score 17):

For truly portable code, `EXIT_FAILURE` is preferred. The C standard only defines meaning for three values: `EXIT_FAILURE`, `0`, and `EXIT_SUCCESS` (with `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` essentially synonymous).

From a practical viewpoint, *most* typical systems accept other values as well. If memory serves, Linux will let you return any 8-bit value, and Windows 16-bit values. Unless you honestly might care about porting to an IBM mainframe, VMS, etc., chances are you don't care about most of the systems that won't support at least 8-bit return values.

Answer (score 6):

Use `EXIT_FAILURE`. It is a constant that is used throughout the OS. Its value could be something else than 1 and also it is more descriptive in the code.

Comment: Is it a constant throughout *multiple* OS's?

Comment: @Aerovistae: `EXIT_FAILURE` is specified by the C standard, and has been since 1989. It will be available on any reasonably modern C compiler. Its value is typically `1`, but it will always be the correct value that denotes failed program execution in the current OS.

Answer (score 4):

There are conventions for what sorts of status values certain programs should return. The most common convention is simply 0 for success and 1 for failure. Programs that perform comparison use a different convention: they use status 1 to indicate a mismatch, and status 2 to indicate an inability to compare. Your program should follow an existing convention if an existing convention makes sense for it.

> Some non-POSIX systems use different conventions for exit status
>   values. `For greater portability`, you can use the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS`
>   and `EXIT_FAILURE` for the conventional status value for success and
>   failure, respectively. They are declared in the file stdlib.h.

Answer (score 1):

Not only VMS has its own rules also AmigaDOS defines a return code below 5 as okay.