# Reading file when compiling

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I'm working on a program and it's something I can't understand. I have a main function with arguments:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if( file == NULL )
    {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

How do I read the `argv[1]` file. When I compile it error shows up as Invalid argument. How do I get the file to open so I can print the things it's hiding? I'm using Code Blocks.

Comment: You are missing some `#include` directives, notably for `<stdio.h>`

Comment: Compile on the command line (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g yourprog.c -o prog-bin` if your C source file is `yourprog.c`) and show us the exact error messages. And the computer is not reading a file when *compiling* but at run time.

Answer (score 3):

The argv[1] refers to the first argument passed by the user on the command line.  argv[0] refers to the file itself.  So in your case, the program will open the file passed as the first argument.

```
./myprogram myfilename.txt
```

Moreover, you have a few issues with the program itself.

```
    #include <stdio.h>  /* Library needed for input/output*/    
    #include <stdlib.h> /* needed for the exit calls*/

    int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
        FILE *file;
        file=fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if( file == NULL )
        {
            perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        return 0;
        }
```

This obviously doesnt do much right now but it will get argv1 open.
Also, I changed exit(EXIT_FAILURE) to exit(1).  They are mostly synonymous but exit(1) doesn't require a compiler flag (-std=c99).  EXIT_FAILURE is considered more portable - [EXIT_FAILURE vs exit(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667364/exit-failure-vs-exit1) - but again for simplicity, I changed it to exit(1).

Comment: Thanks. But I stills don't really understand how I should open the file. For now it's called main.c and it's in a project in Code Blocks. Can I just run it from the cmd or am I missing something again?

Comment: No problem.  I think what you need to do is go to Projects -> Set Program Arguments, and set the name of the program you want as argv[1].

Comment: Just a note: `EXIT_FAILURE` does not require any compiler flags--just `#include <stdlib.h>`. Adding `-std=c99` to the compile command line just tells the compiler to warn about things that weren't part of that standard--leaving it off tells the compiler that we don't care about complying with a particular standard, so don't warn about anything that the compiler recognizes as valid, including extensions. Additionally, `EXIT_FAILURE` was already defined in C89, so I don't know of any set of flags that would cause the compiler to warn about its use.