# The return type of main() function

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I get this code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(void) 
{ 
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(10); 

    if(NULL == ptr) 
    { 
        printf("\n Malloc failed \n"); 
        return; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // Do some processing 
        free(ptr); 
    } 

    return; 
}
```

It compiles successfully in Visual C, but do not compile in gcc, I get "error:'main' must return 'int'". So is the return type 'int' of main() function is a convention(which is for compiler to define), or a rule of C?

Comment: main() should always return int,

Comment: ditto, return codes are always INT, examples: -1, 0, etc.. You should also initialize the value.

Comment: I posted void main() on one of the hardcore ansi-C newsgroups about 10 years ago.  I don't think I've ever had more vitriol thrown my way.  I wasn't even posting about that; it was just a part of the snippet from an embedded system that I was asking a question about.  On that tiny CPU, main() returning would be a catastrophic failure (it was firmware; it should run forever) but those guys didn't care.  Never got my question answered, just spent the rest of the time explaining how main couldn't return.  Now I always return int, even when main() will never return.

Comment: On a freestanding implementation, the return type of `main()` should be whatever the implementation tells you to use. Even the hardcore Ansi-C people over at comp.lang.c should know that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says:

> #### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> <sup>10)</sup>  Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of argv can be written as
>   `char **argv`, and so on.

Thus, the only portable declaration for `main()` has a return type of `int`.  If MSVC defines that `void` is permitted ('or in some other implementation-defined manner'), so be it, but do not expect the code to be portable.  The old versions of the Microsoft compilers (up to and including MSVC 2005) do not permit `void main()`: see the documentation at [`main`: Program startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [The `main` Function and Program Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ze4ytsc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However, MSVC 2008 and later are documented to allow `void main()`: see [`main`: Program Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx). The three-argument form of `main()` is noted as a common extension in Appendix J:

> ### J.5 Common extensions
>
> The following extensions are widely used in many systems, but are not portable to all
>   implementations. The inclusion of any extension that may cause a strictly conforming
>   program to become invalid renders an implementation nonconforming. Examples of such
>   extensions are new keywords, extra library functions declared in standard headers, or
>   predefined macros with names that do not begin with an underscore.
>
> #### J.5.1 Environment arguments
>
> In a hosted environment, the `main` function receives a third argument, `char *envp[]`,
>   that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to `char`, each of which points to a string
>   that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program
>   (5.1.2.2.1).

---

The value returned from `main()` is transmitted to the 'environment' in an implementation-defined way.

> #### 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> 1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
>   initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value
>   returned by the `main` function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main` function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.
>
> <sup>11)</sup> In accordance with 6.2.4, the lifetimes of objects with automatic storage duration declared in `main`
>   will have ended in the former case, even where they would not have in the latter.

Note that `0` is mandated as 'success'.  You can use `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `<stdlib.h>` if you prefer, but 0 is well established, and so is 1.  See also [Exit codes greater than 255 — possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/exitcodes-bigger-than-255-possible/).

> #### 7.22.4.4 The `exit` function
>
> ¶5 Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of `status` is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status *successful termination* is returned. If the value of `status` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status *unsuccessful termination* is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

Comment: I think for OP it should be added that `int` before main is process termination status, when process done

Comment: I was just about to quote the same from C standard . +1 anyway :)

Comment: Quote of C standard is helpful.

Comment: @lulyon One more thing I would like to add: just not return `0` or `1` instead use [`EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Any reason why doing so? cause normally I do not use EXIT_SUCCESS too. Using macros in the context seems unnecessary.

Comment: @lulyon I also use `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`, [Read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/c-c-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

`void main()` is non-standard C and `int main()` is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

According to c standard `main()` should return integer for informing success or failure.Generally for success it returns zero and for failure it returns a integer value(either positive or negative).
Generally main is declared as

```
 int main(void);
```

so it expects integer as return type.

If command line arguments are there,

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]);
```

Comment: So while running the program how do we know it is returning 0 or 1 ?