# why am I getting runtime error?

Tags: c, runtime-error

I know that runtime error occurs when program consumes large memory or divide by 0 somewhere.
this is the code which prints all the numbers until user types 42.(does not print 42).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    while(1)
    {

        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n==42)
            break;
        else
            printf("%d",n);

    }
}
```

please tell me why am I getting runtime error in such a simple code?

Comment: What kind of runtime error? Please post the complete error message as formatted text.

Comment: Is it _time limit_ ?

Comment: 'runtime error' is shown by codechef.

Comment: please post the run time error also, so that we help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your main function should return a int and you're not: that's why you get a Runtime Error. Here is the correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    while(1) {

        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n == 42)
            break;
        else
            printf("%d",n);

    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can also change `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` in `return 0;` if you don't want to include `stdlib.h` but here is [why it's better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/should-i-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main).

You should also consider using another IDE than CodeChef. CodeBlocks or VisualStudio are better and more explicit with errors and warnings. And you should set you `int n` to 0 before using it.

Comment: So,adding return 0 worked...but **what is the relation of this with runtime error?**the concept of runtime error is like :if you are consuming too much memory from stack then runtime error occurs,right?

Comment: Runtime error doesn't mean that you're using too much memory. It just says an error occurred at runtime because the compiler didn't see the error during compilation. It can be a memory issue, but not always.

Comment: When a program encounters an error it'll exit with a non-zero code. That's why codechef thinks there's some problem with your program

Comment: "*And you should set you `int n` to 0 before using it.*" Why? An explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine as it is **except** when running on CodeChef.

According to the C standard (at least C99 and C11) a `return 0` is implicit when `main()` ends without returning something. So even though it can be argued that it is a good idea to always have a `return 0` at the end of `main()`, it is not wrong to skip it.

But that's not the case when running on CodeChef. For some reason they tread it as a run time error if main does not end with `return 0`.