# C++ return at the end of main()

Tags: c++

I was thinking about implementing my own `exit()` function for educational purpose, only. I know you can manipulate addresses if the OS lets you (for example the OS won't let you manipulate the address 0, it would cause a crash).
So I thought why not sending 0 to that address `return 0` returns to.

```
int main(){
// code...
return 0;
}
```

The `return 0` returns a 'success' to the OS, right? But which address is it? How do I get it? And is the actual exit() from the C standard library implemented this way?

Comment: I think you save some misconceptions about these "adresses the OS lets you manipulate"

Comment: Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense. You should try clarifying.

Comment: `return 0;` returns `0` from the `main` function. The C++ standard doesn't specify what address to jump to when returning from functions, but it's typically stored on the call stack or in a register. Some crt1 implementations use `exit(main(argc, argc, envp))`, so if you configure the linker correctly you could override the `exit` function.

Comment: The argument to `return` is not an address.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff going on in between when you run your program and when `main` gets called, and then when `main` exits and when the OS gets the return status. I think this is perhaps a larger problem than you think it is.

Comment: @JoshG79 your a so right. +`0` means whatever you want it to mean. Fianlly, the answer to your question is, as far as I can understand it, OS and compiler dependent.

Answer (score 4):

When you `return 0`, you do not return to an address.  You are returning the *value* 0.  When a process returns the value 0, it is considered to be normal termination.  You can return a non-zero value (up to 255) that may be interpreted by the calling process as a message.

Let us look at this with an example command `grep foobar fubar`.  It will return 0 (success) if there is the pattern `foobar` in the file `fubar`.  It will return 1 if there is no `foobar` in the file `fubar`.  It will return 2 when there is no file named `fubar`.  The rturn value could be interpreted in the script that makes this command to evaluate the success or reason for failure.

Comment: Well somehow the OS gets the value 0 from the program, right? Where does this value go to?

Comment: @Davlog There is system/implementation specific code that gets executed before and after main is called.

Comment: It is not an address, the OS initializes the program/thread on a process, when the program closes, the last thing on the program stack is the return value, the OS gets the return from that. If you had an specific address to do so you will have a lot of problems.

Comment: You do return to an address.  Not the address `0`, of course, but an address on the stack, that was pushed when the start-up code called `main`.

Comment: @James Kanze i expressed myself on a wrong way.. i tried to say that its not an specific address (all programs return their values using the address 0x00011 (its an example)). Each program have their own address to do so.

Comment: @demonofnight so if I just change the value of that address it will still run?

Comment: @Davlog there is no "address" you are returning a value.

Comment: @Borgleader Demonofnight said "Each program have their own address to do so." And every address holds a value, right?

Comment: @Davlog, you must forget the "address" idea, on the C/C++ there is a bunch of stuffs that happen when you start a program, so let the C/C++ handle that for you. If you want to take a better look at that, dump your C/C++ code to assembler. the _start section (if i recall correctly)

Comment: @Davlog The return uses an specific register, registers have pointers.. so yes, it is a pointer. BUT the C/C++ handles that, "you don't have how to know what is the pointer"...

Answer (score 4):

The exit code is (eventually) stored into the Process Control Block so that the OS can report the result value to other processes.

See http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/compsci340s2c/lectures/lecture06.pdf

However, the `return` statement isn't what does this.  Your runtime library is actually calling `main` more-or-less like a normal function, gets the return value (on Intel, a return value of type `int` would be stored in the `EAX` register), and then requests that the kernel write it to the TCB.  `exit()` also invokes the kernel to write this member of the TCB.

Comment: `exit` and returning from `main` do a lot more than that.  (And of course, they don't write anything directly to the PCB, supposing that the OS has one; they call an OS specific primitive with the return code which takes care of all of this.)

Comment: @James: Clarified that the actual write is done by the kernel, at the request of the process.

Comment: Yes.  The critical part is that at some point, `exit` will invoke a kernel level primitive to tell it to terminate the process; this kernel level primitive will update the PCB (or whatever the kernel coders decided to call it), with the return code (which is passed as an argument to this kernel primitive), but also with information which will prevent the process from being scheduled; this primitive will also reclaim all of the resources of the process, and possibly record some accounting information.

Comment: @James: I guess all the resources *except* the TCB, which exists as a zombie process until `wait` reaps it.  Closing handles is a very important part of `exit` of course.

Comment: Pretty much.  `exit` flushes and closes the high level file structures, but if anything is forgotten, the system will close the low level file descriptors as part of cleaning up after the process.  (I implemented a C runtime, many, many years ago, and `exit` is anything but trivial.)

Answer (score 2):

The `return 0;` in `main` works like a `return` anywhere; it
returns to the place from which it was called.  When you start
a program, the system does *not* start it at `main`, but at some
start-up address which does a lot of initializations, and then
something like:

```
exit( main(/*...*/) );
```

In other words, `exit` does not simulate a return from `main`;
returning from `main` calls `exit`.  And exit then does a lot of
shutting down, before calling some system specific function 
which tells the system to stop the process (`_exit` under Unix).

You cannot implement `exit` yourself, because you have no way of
finding the information it needs: the list of functions
registered with `atexit` which need to be called, the list of
destructors of objects with static lifetime, etc.

Comment: «You cannot implement exit yourself» — FALSE! If somebody else did it then you can certainly do it yourself, too. After all, you can even intercept call to `exit()` and supply your own implementation.

Comment: @VladLazarenko You cannot implement `exit` yourself, for the reasons I enumerated.  `exit` does a lot more than just return to the system; it must clean up.  And the lists of things it has to do are _not_ global symbols which you can access, and do not have externally defined structures so that you know what to do about them.  `exit` works with the rest of the C run time library, and to implement `exit`, you need the sources of the C run time library.

Comment: I think that's important to outline the fact that `atexit` it's not related to the standard library but it's implemented in the C++ ABI library of choice, in other words, it's a symbol that is not granted to be there and it's something that is platform specific.

Comment: Hell I can! Why not? Who do you think implemented an `exit()` function that you call, the Gods? As for the return statement in main(), see §5.1.2.2.3 Program Termination. Since C99, the return value in that case is 0.

Comment: @user2485710 `atexit()` is defined in §7.22.4.2 of the
C standard, and by reference in §18.5 of the C++ standard.  It
is _not_ platform specific.  (How it is implemented is, of
course.)

Comment: @VladLazarenko "Who do you think implemented an exit() function that you call": the same people who implemented the C run time.  The function is integrated into the C run time, and needs to access data structures and variables which are defined there.  If you have the sources of the C runtime, and know how to link them (because you can't link them like a normal program), then you can implement `exit`.  Otherwise, you cannot.

Comment: @JamesKanze on my linux desktop is implemented in my libsupc++ library and not in libstdc++, it's about the ABI not about the standard library.

Comment: So at the end of the day it turns out that I can. That's the whole point, why say «You cannot implement exit yourself». If that was true, we'd have no exit() function :)

Comment: @user2485710 It's specified in the C and the C++ standards as part of the standard library.  Under "normal" Unix, it's implemented in `libc.so`, but that's irrelevant.  It's defined by the language.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I said "_YOU_ cannot implement `exit` yourself", because _you_ can't.  The people implementing the C run time, of course, are in a different context, where they can.

Comment: How do you know I do not implement a C run time? Maybe at nights when the moon is full I cannot sleep and keep crafting my own C runtime on top of my own «Big Mess of Wires» CPU?

Comment: @Vlad: I think the point James is trying to make is "You cannot have an application-specific `exit` implementation while still using the rest of the library, `exit` and a lot of the other runtime support must be implemented together."

Comment: @VladLazarenko Because if you did, you wouldn't ask such a question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Exactly.  Functions like these are part of a whole, and cannot be implemented separately.  In a similar manner, things like `std::type_info` cannot be implemented independently of the compiler.  Unlike something like `std::string`, which is (or can be) fairly independent of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main confusion here is the notion that that `main` is the first and last thing that happens in C++ program. Whilst it is [1] the first part of YOUR program, there is usually some code in the application that sets up a few things, parses command line arguments, opening/initialization of standard I/O (`cin`, `cout`, etc) and other such things, which happen BEFORE `main` is called. And `main` is essentially just another function, called by the C++ runtime functionality that does that "fix things up before `main`".

So, when `main` returns, it goes back to the code that called it, which then cleans up the things that need cleaning up (closing standard I/O channels, and many other such things), before actually finishing up by calling some OS function to "terminate this process". As part of this "terminate this process" functionality is (in most OS's) a way to signal "success or failure" to the OS, so that some other process monitoring the application can determine "if all is well or not". This is where, eventually, the `0` (or `1` if you use `return 1;` in `main`) ends up.

[1] If there are static objects with constructors that are part of the user's code, then these will be performed before any code in `main` [or at least, before any code in `main` that belongs to the user's application] is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is because of not understanding what `return` does. Take this function for example:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
   return (x + y);
}
```

The return in above function and the return statement at the end of your `main` function are exactly the same, *from a language standpoint* they mean the same. The meaning of that is to return an integer to the caller. What the caller makes out of this value is completely another thing which depends on the caller's intention of calling said function. Say I can call `add(7, 9);` to add two GPA grades while another programmer might call it to find the sum of all the money in a couple of bank accounts.

Now `main` is treated as a special function since it is the first function the operating system, or more specifically its loader, calls to being your program. After your program completes, whatever `main` returns might mean anything based on the OS's semantics. This value has nothing to do with any memory address.

**Aside:** According to the standard, in C++ (and C99 onawards) the `return 0;` statement can be omitted to mean a successful termination of the program.

Comment: That depends on which version of C, doesn't it?

Comment: @BenVoigt: You mean the omission of `return 0;` at the end of main?

Comment: You can safely omit main`s `return 0;` in C as well. In C99.

Comment: The standard requires that an implementation recognize `0` as success, as well as `EXIT_SUCCESS`.  On systems such as the old DEC OS's, where odd numbers signaled success, the C run time had to remap `0` to an odd number.

Comment: @legends2k: Yes, that's the only reference to C in your answer and it is what I was commenting about.  I found this rule "reaching 
 the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0."

Comment: @VladLazarenko Where does it say that in the C standard?  I can't find it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks, removed `EXIT_SUCCESS` detail from the answer. Saw the same information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188335/why-default-return-value-of-main-is-0-and-not-exit-success) too

Comment: @BenVoigt: I didn't know from C99 onwards one can omit `return 0;`. I saw it written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8868139/183120).

Comment: @legends2k That's not a confirmation.  It just says that someone
else thinks so too (although the person in question has
a tendancy to be right about such things).  The confirmation is
in §5.1.2.2.3 of C11.  (The statement may have been present in
earlier versions as well.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Alright, I confirmed it now from [the publicly available C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) :) And yes, the same section states it.

Answer (score 0):

If m understanding is correct, there will be a SIGCHLD signal that would be sent on exit to main shell which contains the return value... This should happen when the PCB is destroyed by the kernel...

But if you want to hook up certain functionality while exiting from the code, you can register a handler at atexit() as per POSIX implementation..

I dont think you can modify how the return valur propagates at user level, since the control of the program reaches the PC in another process ( of which you dont have access to).

Comment: The PCB isn't destroyed by the kernel until it is reaped by `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ abi library implements the symbol `__cxa_atexit` you can use [`atexit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/)

AFAIK the language doesn't really offer other *safe ways* to do something that is user-defined when a program stops the execution.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `function`, it has a type. It can be `int`, `void`, or other. If the function is not void, then it has to return a value. In our case, the `return` value of `main` is `int`, which is usually a `return` code. The convention is that if it is 0, then there was no error, while other values are error codes.